# how to read from mongodb and output in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

How can I output the rows(docs) as html table format without using express/view engine. I tried writing res.write(`${documents}`) which is not working. Please check the following code.

```
const http = require('http');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
var documents;
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("mydb").collection("messages");
  collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.log("Found the following records");
    console.log(docs); // How can write this docs as html table
    documents = docs; // Is there any workaround for this?
  });
  client.close();
});

const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.write(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/. Records:${documents}`); //this document not appearing
  res.end();
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: You need to generate HTML markup from JSON or map JSON to HTML right ?

Comment: If so then try this 
    let  myObj
    txt += "<table border='1'>"
    for (x in myObj) {
      txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].name + "</td></tr>";
    }
    txt += "</table>"
    document =  txt;

Comment: leme know if scope of question is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your code is with Headers

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

you need to set content-type `text/html`

If you want to map JSON to HTML try this

```
let myObj
txt += "<table border='1'>"
for (x in myObj) { txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].name + "</td></tr>"; } 
txt += "</table>" 
document = txt;
```

Comment: Hi Azeen, thanks for your prompt response. I have copy pasted your code. but the output says "undefined". could you please properly format the code and suggest me how to output in res.write()? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Azeen, I corrected the format. now it finally worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your comment on

> // How can write this docs as html table

Have you tried console.table() instead of console.log()?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. console.table() outputted nicely. i want to output such table in browser markup.